# Scanning S3 buckets for auditing purposes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-macie

What is the best way to scan data in S3 (for auditing purposes, possibly)? I was asked to do some research on this and utilizing AWS Athena was my first idea I could think of. But if you can provide more knowledge/ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: scan for what? File changes?

Comment: personal info in files

Comment: How about this article? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudtrail-update-capture-and-process-amazon-s3-object-level-api-activity/ and read more http://blog.panoply.io/an-amazonian-battle-comparing-athena-and-redshift

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Amazon Macie](https://aws.amazon.com/macie/):

> Amazon Macie is a security service that uses machine learning to **automatically discover, classify, and protect sensitive data in AWS**. Amazon Macie recognizes sensitive data such as personally identifiable information (PII) or intellectual property, and provides you with dashboards and alerts that give visibility into how this data is being accessed or moved.

Video: [AWS Summit Series 2017 - New York: Introducing Amazon Macie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xzhW-2aD4s)